# Mean & Standard Deviation bell curved graph using high chart and php

Tags: php, graph, highcharts

I have a Mean & Standard Deviation graph in my website like the image below

[image]

My data set values are  22,65,65,43. How can I draw bell curved graph using these data set?

I want to PHP code to generate z score table for above data set and draw graph same as above image.

Comment: You need to calculate other values and then add these points as extra areaspline serie.

Comment: I want to a mathematically calculation to calculate x an y value which plot graph as bell curve.

Comment: So you need to prepare algorithm which will calculate this values, based on your data.